# Outgoing call routing issue Avaya IP Office PBX

Tags: voip, avaya

I have an Avaya IP Office PBX phone system.  There is a T1 coming in for the trunk.  There were 6 numbers associated tot he trunk.  4 of the numbers were taken off by Telco provider and converted to POTS lines and brought into another office off premises from where the PBX is located.  In the new office the lines work fine for both incoming and outgoing calls on the analog POTS.

This issue that we are having is that when dialing any of those 4 numbers internally on the AVAYA system it just rings right back into local system.  i.e.: 96363345 will ring right back into the phone system.  I have gone though IP Office Manager and I cannot see any references to those 4 numbers anywhere.  I am suspecting its the telco but wanted to see if maybe I am missing something on the PBX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Telco still has the numbers associated with your PRI trunk group. Calls from other locations will be routed to analog lines, however when you call out on your PRI the 5ESS switch bounces the call back down the trunk group as a DID. The Telco needs to remove the numbers from the DID list on their switch.

This type of thing is very common actually. C/O techs have to change the number in 3 different places and don't see the point in removing the numbers from the trunk group when the switch routing will send the call to the correct place regardless of the DID list on a trunk group. The problem with that is it creates routing loop problems like yours.